# draggable() error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Out of the blue I see the below error in console. I'm loading

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css"> //head
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> //end of body
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script> //end of body
<script src="belowScript.js"></script> //end of body
```

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function`

belowScript.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function myFunc(e){
       ///some code
       $('#main').draggable({
          containment: $('#net')
       })
       ///some code
    }
});
```

What's wrong and how can I get this solved?

Comment: Sounds like you did not load JQuery UI or it something is conflicting. Do `$("#main")` and `$("#net")` exist?

Comment: @Twisty Thank you. `$('#main')` is dynamic and it is a image that user will be uploading. `$('#net')` exist.

Comment: SInce `$("#main")` is dynamic, I think you will need to call `.draggable()` upon it after it's created to init the drag for it. Otherwise, you may want to switch to using a class selector.

Comment: I posted an answer that I hope helps. Not sure it matches what you're doing. Welcome to comment and I can adjust.

Comment: Maybe the path to libraries or something is incorrect... Maybe the version of jquery is not compatible with the version of jquery ui being used... try creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're going for. I made a few guesses: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ukh1r21t/

**HTML**

```
<h2>Drag Test</h2>
<button id="make">Make (Upload) Image</button>
<div id="net">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#net {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.canDrag {
  margin: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

**JQuery UI**

```
$(function() {
  $("#make").click(function() {
    var i = $(".canDrag").length;
    var newImg = $("<img>", {
      src: "#",
      id: "main-" + i,
      class: "canDrag"
    });
    newImg.draggable({
      containment: $('#net')
    });
    $("#net").append(newImg);
  });
});
```

The new Image object is created and then initialized as a draggable. You can use the Class to format them and they each get their own unique ID. Then you can just set the `src` value as needed.